# please help getting this error while executing

Tags: python

```
next_words = []
for _ in range(next_words):
    token_list = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([seed_text])[0]
    token_list = pad_sequences([token_list], maxlen=max_sequence_length - 1, padding='pre')
    predicted = np.argmax(model.predict(token_list), axis=-1)
    output_word = ""
    for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
        if index == predicted:
            output_word = word
            break
    seed_text += " " + output_word
```

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Probably it should read `for _ in next_words:`.

Comment: And then it won't make any sense, because a loop over an empty list has zero iterations and none of the code will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate number of time the length of list. You can use `len` function for it.

```
for _ in range(len(next_words)):
   ....
   ....
```

Or you can loop over list via

```
for _ in next_words:
   ....
   ....
```

Comment: since `next_words` is empty the loop will never run

Comment: @balderman: While true, this problem is already in the original question. Loops without use of  the loop variable are of course suspicious anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
for _ in range(next_words):
```

is your problem.
you are passing an empty list to [range](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp).
range is expecting to get an int